# Slide out suddenly not working anymore

Tags: android

I use custom animations to change between activities. The goal is that the current activity slides out left and the new slides in from the right. So i defined these animations:

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

And I apply these in my Activity:

```
public void menuLogin (View view)
{
    Intent intent   =   new Intent (this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity (intent);
    overridePendingTransition (R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
}
```

So the strange thing is: until two days ago it totally worked fine. The old activity slided out left and the new slided in from the right. But then it just stopped working. Right now the old activity just disappears and the new slides in. But I didn't change the animation xml or the Java code.

But if I change R.anim.slide_out_left to R.anim.slide_out_right which has the same code except that -100% is 100% in toXDelta the animation is shown correctly. It just doesn't work if it's -100%.

I've already restarted the emulator, restarted my computer, checked for updates of the SDK, deleted the device and created a new one, and cleaned my project.
The emulator device is a Nexus One, CPU Intel Atom x86, Android 4.4.2, Host GPU and my computer is a Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why I haven't thought of this before:
I created another emulator device with the same settings (Nexus One, Android 4.4.2, Host GPU) but with CPU **ARM** and somehow the slide effect works again.